Convert from local to absolute coordinate having four georeferenced points
I am attempting to determine the absolute positions of several points acquired via a total station survey. I had also obtained local coordinates for four points (the vertices of the red polyline) that had previously been georeferenced using GPS. Is there a method to utilize this information to obtain absolute coordinates for the remaining local points? I am using AutoCAD and QGIS


If you have at least 3 tie points you can create a >>>custom affine projection<<< using the Geoscience Plugin in QGIS.

You can use Georeferencer for vector layers, too. Construct you vector layer with local coordinates and save it. Open it in gereferencer and define control point for transformation.
